# How to position a TextView contents after changing .setScaleY() and .setScaleX()?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, escpos

I'm trying to make an android ESC/POS printer editor UI. ESC/POS has few options when printing text and they can be mixed together: small, underlined, bold, double width(wide), double height(tall).
While the ESC/POS printer part is no problem, I have some issues while trying to represent it with text views in android UI.

while 'small' could be solved changing the font size, i'm trying to achieve
wide and tall by setting View.setScaleX(1.5f) and View.setScaleY(1.5f).

I am creating those views programmaticaly and adding them to a linearLayout container.

After changing scale the view bounds does not get updated. and wide option goes out of view bounds. I have tried to use view.invalidate() on view and its parent thinking it would recalculate bounds but it did not work.

```
onClick(View v) {
            PrinterCommands.FormatedText textComand = new PrinterCommands.FormatedText("Hello world");
            textComand.setTall(r.nextBoolean());
            textComand.setUnderlined(r.nextBoolean());
            textComand.setBold(r.nextBoolean());
            textComand.setWide(r.nextBoolean());
            textComand.setSmall(r.nextBoolean());


            TextView textView = new TextView(CommandsViewActivity.this);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello world");
            // v.setText(String.valueOf(position));
            if (textComand.isSmall()) {
                sb.append(" small");
                textView.setScaleX(0.5f);
                textView.setScaleY(0.5f);
            }
            if (textComand.isBold()) {
                sb.append(" bold");
                textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            }
            if (textComand.isTall()) {
                sb.append(" tall");
                textView.setScaleY(1.5f);
            }
            if (textComand.isWide()){
                sb.append(" wide");
                textView.setScaleX(1.5f);
            }

            if (textComand.isUnderlined()) {
                sb.append(" underlined");
                SpannableString s = new SpannableString(sb.toString());
                s.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, s.length(), 0);
                textView.setText(s);
            } else textView.setText(sb.toString());

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.START|Gravity.CENTER);

            p.setMargins(16,16,16,16);
            textView.setLayoutParams(p);
            container.addView(textView);

        }
    });
```

[Layout output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT0wv.png)